# Google Script to convert a Google Sheet to Excel and Email it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Every week I have a few different Google Sheets that I have to download as excel, delete hidden rows, fix data and then email out.

This can be very time consuming, so I would like to make/deploy a script that automates this process.

I did a ton of searching to try to get this to work, however I am running into a few issues.

First, the data in the sheet is pulled via a query/importrange formula, so once downloaded to excel all data looks like the following:

```
=IFERROR(__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION("""COMPUTED_VALUE"""),"No")
```

This prevents being able to filter any of the data. Currently I'm fixing this by copying all data in excel and pasting values only. I'd like the excel file to be corrected so that I don't have to do that.

Also, I would like to be able to email the converted Excel file.

I found the following code that works for this:

```js
function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel(){
  
  try {
    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ss.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
    
    var params = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };
    
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
    
    blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".xlsx");
    
    MailApp.sendEmail("amit@labnol.org", "Google Sheet to Excel", "The XLSX file is attached", {attachments: [blob]});
    
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}
```

This mostly works, but again runs into the issue above of the importrange data being incorrect and showing as the =IFERROR(__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION.

There are also two columns (A and J) that are hidden and need to be deleted.

Additionally, I would love to be able to change the email address, subject and message via an GUI. But this is much less important and not needed.

I know that this is a big ask, but any help would be amazing!

Comment: You can write a google script function to replace cell values populated by an `importrange` formula with the actual values, and call that before downloading / emailing the sheet. I suggest focusing this question on that issue, and separating your other issues (like email GUI) into other SO questions.

Comment: @DustinMichels+1 Personally, I'd create a copy of the Google spreadsheet and then use the `copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)` command [Doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-copypastetype-transposed) to copy the sheets, converting the formulas to values. Then convert those sheets to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

This script addresses part of your question.

1. Create a copy of a sheet, and in the process convert formulas to values
2. Delete columns

Note: There are several options for converting the formula to values.

So far as changing the email address, subject and message via a GUI, I suggest using a [custom sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars).

---

```
function so5665379502(){
  /*
  // The purpose of this script is to copy the content of one sheet to another;
  // converting formulas to values 
    // and deleting columns
  */

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetname = "ejbsheet01";
    var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname); 
  var destname = "ejbsheet02";
    var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destname);
    sourcesheet.activate();
  var range = sourcesheet.getDataRange();
  var rFC = range.getColumn();
  var rLC = range.getLastColumn();
  var rFR = range.getRow();
  var rLR = range.getLastRow();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the data range = "+range.getA1Notation()+", column 1 = "+rFC+", the last column = "+rLC+", first row = "+rFR+", last row = "+rLR);

  //  syntax copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)
  range.copyValuesToRange(destinationSheet, rFC, rLC, rFR, rLR);

  // delete column J first so that other column numbers don't chnage.
  // column J = 10
  destinationSheet.deleteColumn(10);
  // Delete Column A
  // column A = 1
  destinationSheet.deleteColumn(1);  
}
```

---

**BEFORE**
Note: Columns A and J are hidden
[image: BEFORE]

---

**AFTER**
Note: The hidden Columns are gone and the data ais values, not formula.
[image: AFTER]

Comment: Hello. How could I clone the sheet without lose the style of the source sheet?

Comment: Hi @Gavis Please ask this as a new question. Make sure that you describe EXACTLY what you mean by "sheet" (Spreadsheet file, or a single "sheet"/tab), and what you mean by "clone", and describe the EXACT process that you follow when the formatting on the new sheet is not the same as the source.

Comment: Hi @tedinoz here you can see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71571243/consider-only-some-cells-with-formula-when-export-excel-file-from-sheet