# Consider only some cells with formula when export excel file from sheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

With this code I can export an excel file from a spreadsheet keeping the style and formulas for all the cells, but I am trying to exclude the formulas in the excel from some ranges and convert them in plain text.

In particular the range that I would to convert in plain text excluding the formulas are:

- A5:A400
- B5:B400
- D5:D400
- E5:E400
- J5:J400

In addition, this code export in excel all the tabs but I am trying to export only the active tab till the column J.

How could I edit the code in order to solve this 2 improvements?

Regards

```
function downloadXLS_GUI2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .copy("new_copy")
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]
  const numRows = 10;
  sheet
    .getRange(1, numRows + 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
    .clear()
  const URL = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=xlsx`;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showDialog(
      HtmlService
        .createHtmlOutput(`<a href="${URL}" target="_blank">Download</a>`)
    )
}
```

[image: Current result]

Comment: Can you show what you have tested so far? The script you show, if I remember correctly, is the one I added in another of your [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71440451/14271633).

Comment: Hello! Yes I have tested your solution (Update 2) but the excel generated doesn't take the style of the sheet. While with the code on top, the excel take the style of the sheet but pull in the excel all the formulas

Comment: From what I see, this is exactly the code from my first answer, and I can also see in the comments that I suggested the next steps to take, have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: I have added your string to my original code, but the script return me a blank sheet. So I am trying to find a solution to generate the excel directly without those formulas for those ranges but keeping the style of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Please update your questions showing how you implement it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function downloadXLS_GUI2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().copy("new_copy");
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.deleteRows(5, sh.getLastRow() - 4);
  sheet.deleteColumns(11,2);
  const URL = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=xlsx`;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<a href="${URL}" target="_blank">Download</a>`), "My new Spreadsheet");
}
```

Downloaded file:

[image]

#### This version also provides a button to delete the local copy of the file and close the dialog.

```
function downloadXLS_GUI2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().copy("new_copy");
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.getRange(11, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 10, sheet.getLastColumn()).clear()
  const URL = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=xlsx`;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<a href="${URL}" target="_blank">Download</a><br /><input type="button" value="Delete Copy after Down Load" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close()}).deleteTheCopy('${ss.getId()}');" />`),"My Copy");
}

function deleteTheCopy(id) {
  Drive.Files.remove(id)
}
```

- Advanced Drive API version 2 must be enabled.

The Dialog:

[image]

Comment: Hello @cooper thanks for your reply, the style is replicated but your code show me the formulas in the ranges of the excel file I have mentioned in the question. Why it happens?

Comment: I have upload an image on the question with current situation of the excel file. As you can see, the style is ok, but the formula must be excluded on yellow columns (from the row 5) with plain text